# How a thread should close itself in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a short question. At some point my thread understand that it should suicide. What is the best way to do it:

1. Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
2. return;

By the way, why in the first case we need to use `currentThread`? Is `Thread` does not refer to the current thread?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you want to terminate the *thread*, then just returning is fine. You do NOT need to call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` (it will not do anything bad though. It's just that you don't need to.) This is because `interrupt()` is basically used to notify the owner of the thread (well, not 100% accurate, but sort of). Because you are the owner of the thread, and you decided to terminate the thread, there is no one to notify, so you don't need to call it.

> By the way, why in the first case we
>   need to use currentThread? Is Thread
>   does not refer to the current thread?

Yes, it doesn't. I guess it can be confusing because e.g. Thread.sleep() affects the current thread, but Thread.sleep() is a static method.

If you are NOT the owner of the thread (e.g. if you have not extended `Thread` and coded a `Runnable` etc.) you should do

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
return;
```

This way, whatever code that called your runnable will know the thread is interrupted = (normally) should stop whatever it is doing and terminate. As I said earlier, it is just a mechanism of communication though. The owner might simply ignore the interrupted status and do nothing.. but if you do set the interrupted status, somebody might thank you for that in the future.

For the same reason, you should never do

```
Catch(InterruptedException ie){
     //ignore
}
```

Because if you do, you are stopping the message there. Instead one should do

```
Catch(InterruptedException ie){
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();//preserve the message
    return;//Stop doing whatever I am doing and terminate
}
```

Comment: Last part: Why do I need to call interrupt if the thread was milliseconds ago interrupted? :)

Comment: @JacksOnF1re: Because in its infinite wisdom, Java decided that interruption flag are set to false when `InterruptedException` is thrown. I.e. unless you call interrupt, the caller would not notice the thread is interrupted because `isInterrupted` will start to return false.

Answer (score 19):

If the run method ends, the thread will end.

If you use a loop, a proper way is like following:

```
// In your imlemented Runnable class:
private volatile boolean running = true;

public void run()
{
   while (running)
   {
      ...
   }
}


public void stopRunning()
{
    running = false;
}
```

Of course returning is the best way.

Comment: @Martijn: You need to make `running` volatile, or else you have a concurrency bug.

Comment: @Zwei: Only if you want to signal it from a different thread - in this case it sounds like the thread itself knows (at some point) that it ought to stop.

Comment: @Jon: Could be, but personally, regardless of the situation, if stopRunning() is `public`, I believe it is very dangerous to use a non-volatile flag. You can easily forget that, call stopRunning() from another thread and have a really nasty bug...

Comment: Can I resume the execution by setting `running` to `true`? I want to give it a `pause` instead of `termination`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're at the top level - or able to cleanly *get* to the top level - of the thread, then just returning is nice. Throwing an exception isn't as clean, as you need to be able to check that nothing's going to catch the exception and ignore it.

The reason you need to use `Thread.currentThread()` in order to call `interrupt()` is that `interrupt()` is an instance method - you need to call it on the thread you want to interrupt, which in your case happens to be the current thread. Note that the interruption will only be noticed the next time the thread would block (e.g. for IO or for a monitor) anyway - it doesn't mean the exception is thrown immediately.

Comment: @Downvoter: Could you explain what you didn't like about my answer?

Answer (score 5):

If you simply call `interrupt()`, the thread will not automatically be closed. Instead, the Thread might even *continue* living, if `isInterrupted()` is implemented accordingly. The only way to guaranteedly *close* a thread, as asked for by OP, is

```
Thread.currentThread().stop();
```

Method is deprecated, however.

Calling `return` only returns from the current method. This only terminates the thread if you're at its top level.

Nevertheless, you should work with `interrupt()` and build your code around it.

Comment: This will work, but `stop` has been deprecated since java 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Thread is a class, not an instance; currentThread() is a static method that returns the Thread instance corresponding to the calling thread.

Use (2). interrupt() is a bit brutal for normal use.