# Java - url.openStream cannot work with multi-thread

Tags: java

This is a explicit problem when I tried to read `json text` from a url. I tested in the `URLReader`'s `main` function it returns text fine. But when I call the method outside the class in a thread, IDE didn't report any `Exception`s nor messages, until I traced back to the `URLReader`.

```
public static String loadText(String path) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(path);

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) { /* <--- where it goes wrong */
        String inputLine;
        String lines = "";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            lines += inputLine;
        } return lines;
    } 
}
```

The line `url.openStream()` kept silent from outside call of a thread, but strangely, it always works fine in its own `main`. For example, which leads to a `<html>` text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(text("https://google.com"));
}
```

-----------------------------------   some code here   ---------------------------------------

The thread looks like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        try { Update.updateRecord(); }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}); 

t.start();
```

What could possibly be the problem?

---

**EDIT:**

As [manouti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064245/manouti) mentioned, I have a few threads along with `Thread t`. When I leave `t.start();` alone, it worked perfectly, but not with other threads.

```
Thread t1, t2, t;

/* defined runnable() here */
t1.start(); t2.start(); t.start(); // <--- went wrong

t.start(); // <--- perfectly
```

**EDIT:**

I reminded that in thread `t1` and `t2` I called `System.exit(0);`, which resulted exit of the process not only the thread.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem but in your `Runnable` you're catching an exception and not doing anything with it.

Comment: I dont see any call to `loadText()` in class `Update`

Comment: @ortis `Ticker.last()` returns a `Double` value according to the json text. I couldn't be too explicit here.

Comment: @knh170 You need to show us the code of `API.Ticker.last()`.

Comment: @manouti I have a few calls to threads in parallel with `Thread t`. When I comment the line `t1.start(); t2.start(); ..` and leave alone `t.start();`, it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The explicit problem was caused by a line of `System.exit(0);` from another thread.

[How a thread should close itself in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491588/how-a-thread-should-close-itself-in-java) explained how to exit a thread, otherwise, `exit(0)` will interrupt the **process**, not only the *thread*.